# Releasing java memory before jobs.removeElementAt(i)

Tags: multithreading, performance, memory, deadlock, job-scheduling

i am having the below method in my Java class. When the below method executes the memory keeps on increasing. If i call  jobs.removeElementAt(i); the memory is released. But this is happening when if (updateJobNode(jn) == null). At this situation only the memory is released from jvm. i need to release the memory before executing the updateJobNode(jn). Is there is any possibilities of doing so ?.. Waiting for your positive reply.

```
private synchronized long runJobs( ) {

                    long minDiff = Long.MAX_VALUE;

                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis( );



                    for (int i=0; i < jobs.size( );) {

                            JobNode jn = (JobNode) jobs.elementAt(i);

                            if (jn.executeAt.getTime( ) <= now) {

                                    if (tp != null) {

                                            tp.addRequest(jn.job);

                                    } else {

                                            Thread jt = new Thread(jn.job);

                                            jt.setDaemon(false);

                                            jt.start( );

                                    }

                                    if (updateJobNode(jn) == null) {

                                            jobs.removeElementAt(i);

                                            dlock.release( );

                                    }

                            } else {

                                    long diff = jn.executeAt.getTime( ) - now;

                                    minDiff = Math.min(diff, minDiff);

                                    i++;

                            }

                    }

                    return minDiff;

            }
```